# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472

Tags: vb.net

when i set Excel apllications displayalert propery to true this exception is fired...
why?

Comment: Can you give anymore data?  About the exception? Your code? etc...

Comment: @Tony
objExcelAppDataSheet.DisplayAlerts = True
is only the line, where i get exception
objExcelAppDataSheet is the name of the excel sheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the property browser suspended? If so, this might help: [HRESULT 800ac472 from set operations in Excel](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/9168f9f2-e5bc-4535-8d7d-4e374ab8ff09/)

---

One suggestion is to put your call inside a try block inside a loop, and keep trying the call until it succeeds. It might look something like this:

```
retry = True

Do
    Try
        'Put your call here.
        retry = False
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Need to try again,
        'If this isn't the 0x800ac472 exception it should be re-thrown,
        'Use Sleep(50) to reduce the number of retries,
        'Use Exit Do or re-throw the exception to give up.
    End Try
While retry
```

I don't write in VB myself, so apologies for any mistakes.

Comment: One suggestion is to put your call inside a try block inside a loop, and keep trying the call until it succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

the vb.net code, loop and retry until range.value is accepted to system.array

```
            Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
            Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(paths)
            Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet=wb.Worksheets(1)
            Dim range As Excel.Range = Nothing               
            range = ws.UsedRange
            Dim wh As System.Array
            Dim retryRange As Boolean = False
            While retryRange
                Try
                    wh = range.Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault)
                    retryRange = False
                Catch ex As Exception
                    retryRange = True
                End Try
            End While
```

vb,net code for richj answer

Comment: Please add an explanation of your answer.