# DataGridView problem (import to excel) C#

Tags: c#, excel, windows, datagridview

i have a problem with this part of the code more precisely with:

```
 worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
```

when executing this line it gives me:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472'

```
private void Save()
          {
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new 
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = 
      app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;

    app.Visible = true;
    worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
    worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
    worksheet.Name = "Exported from gridview";

    for(int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++) 
    {
        worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this link maybe help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808057/writing-data-from-c-sharp-to-excel-interrupted-by-opening-excel-window

Comment: Have you considered using a `try-catch-finally` construct? You may be able to get more info by catching the exception. And without question, use the `finally` clause to “clean up” the Excel COM objects the code is creating to avoid leaking resources. I ran the posted code and was unable to reproduce the error, the code appears to work as expected. Are you sure this code is throwing the error?