# SpecialCells throws exception HRESULT: 0x800AC472

Tags: c#, excel

I'm writing a code in C# that reads input from Excel file and place it into objects. when I try to get the last row, sometimes I get an exception HRESULT: 0x800AC472.
this is the code:

```
Excel.Application ExcelObj = new Excel.Application();
        ExcelObj.Visible = false;
        Excel.Workbook workBook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(Name);
        Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)ExcelObj.Sheets[1];
        int lastRow = 0;
        try {
            lastRow=sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row;
        }
```

I've searched google for a solution but found nothing. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this MSDN question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9168f9f2-e5bc-4535-8d7d-4e374ab8ff09/hresult-800ac472-from-set-operations-in-excel?forum=vsto).  What he says to do is to create a retry loop around your code.  [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952759/exception-from-hresult-0x800ac472) had a similar problem that this technique seemed to resolve.